# Woocommerce Set Default Variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce some customers forget to select the variations or they don't know that they must select a variation first, so they keep clicking on the add to cart button but it doesn't work for them and they email me wondering why.

So, I thought of setting the first variation as default for all of the products.
I know I can do this through the admin but I cannot do this for all the products one by one, it's time consuming.
Please is there a code to add/edit to make the first variation the one selected by default?

Comment: There is a plugin to do this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-default-variant-for-woocommerce/ Doesn’t it meet your needs? What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 2):

I once were about to do the same and what i've found after searching a bit is this: https://quadlayers.com/default-product-attributes-woocommerce/

Basically he just hooks into woocommerce_before_single_product_summary and applies some logic that programmatically set the same thing you would set by going into the backend.

Beside this being maybe a good idea i finally gave up because i had to maintain an order into my variation choices and doing this would have break it for sure in the long term (imagine something like a dimension and you have it sorted, like 10,100,1000. You run the code today and it sets 10 as the default, then one day you add 5 and it is no longer correct)

Maybe you should think about giving some visual feedback to your users when they don't select the variation, that might solve the issue and actually create more internet-aware ppls around =)

Comment: H thanks for the link but unfortunately the PHP code didn't work. No variation was set by default.