# Set default first attributes for woocommerce variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I found this question, but no one gave a working answer:
[Woocommerce Set Default Variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025702/woocommerce-set-default-variations)

What is mentioned here doesn't work anymore and I don't understand what the error is:
https://quadlayers.com/default-product-attributes-woocommerce/

Maybe someone knows how to make sure that when entering a variable product, at least some option is selected and the add to cart button is active?

The code that unfortunately no longer works:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'quadlayers_product_default_attributes');
function quadlayers_product_default_attributes() {
      global $product;
      if (!count($default_attributes = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_default_attributes'))) {
        $new_defaults = array();
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if (count($product_attributes)) {
          foreach ($product_attributes as $key => $attributes) {
            $values = explode(',', $product->get_attribute($key));
            if (isset($values[0]) && !isset($default_attributes[$key])) {
              $new_defaults[$key] = sanitize_key($values[0]);
            }
          }
          update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_default_attributes', $new_defaults);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the option to select a '**Default Form Values:**' inside variations tab which lets you select the default option for your variant.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the products have already been loaded and there are a lot of them for manual editing, and with different product imports, it is not always possible to set the initial attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and forth with Claude AI on this and got code that works. I'm here sharing it because it answers a question but also to see if anyone has any concerns about the code it generated:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'quadlayers_set_default_variations');
function quadlayers_set_default_variations() {
    if (is_product()) {
        global $product;

        if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $default_variation = reset($variations);
            $default_attributes = $default_variation['attributes'];
            ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    var defaultAttributes = <?php echo json_encode($default_attributes); ?>;

                    $('.variations_form').find('.variations select').each(function() {
                        var $select = $(this);
                        var attribute = $select.attr('name');
                        var value = defaultAttributes[attribute];

                        if (value) {
                            $select.val(value).trigger('change');
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```